# Operator + undefined for type E(Generic)

Tags: java, generics, java-6

I am trying to add different using generic method. But while returning x + y, we are getting an error stating "Operator + undefined for type E".

```
Thanks,
Alok

public class GenericAdd {
    public static <E extends Number> E add(E x, E y) {
        return x + y;//Operator + undefined for type E
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(add(3,5));
        System.out.println(add(6.3,5));

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, Already same question available. Got my answer. Thanks.